# LaTex error : "Missing } inserted"

Tags: errors

I have written this :

```
\begin{multline}
\Delta T_s = \frac{T_s \times (\alpha \ln \frac{C}{C_0} + (\beta(\sqrt{M} - \sqrt{M_0})\\
- (f(M, N_0) - f(M_0, N_0))) + (\gamma (\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N_0}) - (f(M_0, N) - f(M_0, N_0)))}{4F_{TOA}}
\end{multline}
```

but latex gives me the error "Missing } inserted", i tried some stuff but everytime latex gives me this.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The immediate reason for the error is the fact that you've inserted `\\` in the numerator term of the `\frac` directive. I have removed it and it is works correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\Delta T_s = \frac{T_s \times (\alpha \ln \frac{C}{C_0} + (\beta(\sqrt{M} - \sqrt{M_0})
- (f(M, N_0) - f(M_0, N_0))) + (\gamma (\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N_0}) - (f(M_0, N) - f(M_0, N_0)))}{4F_{TOA}}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

---

To create a line break in the numerator, you can use `\splitfrac`, a macro provided by the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Delta T_s =\frac{\splitfrac{T_s \times [\alpha \ln \frac{C}{C_0} + (\beta(\sqrt{M} - \sqrt{M_0}\,)
- (f(M, N_0) - f(M_0, N_0))] }{+\gamma (\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N_0}\,) - (f(M_0, N) - f(M_0, N_0))}}{4F_{\mathit{TOA}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `\splitfrac`.

Comment: To elaborate, TeX saw `\\ ` inside a group started by `{` instead of the expected closing `}`.  Hence the error message: `Missing } inserted`.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for your advice. If you want you can edit my answer and explain better the reason. My best regards.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use the `\splitfrac` from `mathtools` to make this long fraction fit textwidth. I also used different sizes for parentheses tm make the fraction more readable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \[ \Delta T_s = \frac{\splitfrac{T_s \times\Bigl(\alpha \ln \frac{C}{C_0} + \beta\bigl(\sqrt{M} - \sqrt{M_0}\bigr)
- \bigl(f(M, N_0) - f(M_0, N_0)\bigr)\Bigr)}{+ \Bigl(\gamma \bigl(\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N_0}\bigr) - \bigl(f(M_0, N) - f(M_0, N_0)\bigr)\Bigr)}}{4F_{TOA}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, and I do not want to necro-bump it. However, I feel like the given answers somewhat misses the point. Yes, if you *have* to keep everything in a single equation, `multiline` is the way to go. But do you *really* have to? I can only think of a few circumstances.

- I am submitting to a journal and I am really tight on space
- I am working on a two or three?! column document and are tight on space.

---

In any other circumstance I would recommend rewriting the surrounding text, which will make it more bearable for the reader to digest as well. One suggestion could look like

[image]

Where X and Y needs to be given better names depending on the contect. It looks like you are running some two dimensional iteration scheme, but without context it is hard to suggest better names.

<sup>While a minor detail look how nicely everything is aligned in the top two equations despite M and N having different widths..</sup>

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Now let 
%
\bgroup
\newcommand{\NM}{\mathrlap{N}{\phantom{M}}}
\newcommand{\NMsqrt}{\mathrlap{\sqrt{N_0}}{\phantom{\sqrt{M_0}}}}
\begin{align*}
    X &= \beta\mspace{2mu}(\sqrt{M} - \sqrt{M_0}) - \bigl[f(M, N_0) - f(M_0, N_0)\bigr]\\
    Y &= \gamma\mspace{2mu}(\sqrt{\NM} - \NMsqrt) - \bigl[f(M_0, N) - f(M_0, N_0)\bigr]
\end{align*}
\egroup
%
then the change in $T_s$ is equal to
%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Delta T_s}{T_s}
  = \frac{\alpha \ln(C/C_0) + X + Y}{4F_{TOA}}
\end{equation*}
%
where $T_s$ represents ...
\end{document}
```