# Problem when using \if@xxx in a longtable (or tabular) environment

Tags: tables, longtable, conditionals

I've checked several questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286902/latex-if-condition), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387380/incomplete-iftrue-all-text-was-ignored-after-line), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376763/incomplete-iffalse-all-text-was-ignored-after-line-x-with-lstlisting), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600646/latex-error-missing-inserted)) about a problem with `\if` in a `longtable` (or `tabular`) environment but I haven't managed to get any smarter. I do have the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% some code normally residing in a .sty package
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@test\@testtrue
% [[A
% \newcommand{\thisline}[2]{\if@test\else{ \\ #1 & #2 }\fi}
% \newcommand{\thatline}[2]{\if@test \\ #1 & #2 \else\fi}
% ]] XOR [[B
\newcommand{\thisline}[2]{\if@test\else \\ #1 & #2 \fi}
\newcommand{\thatline}[2]{\if@test{ \\ #1 & #2 }\else\fi}
\@testfalse
% ]]

% user-space code
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  \thisline{a}{b}
  \thatline{c}{d}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The code works like this. However, if I set `\@testfalse`, I have to use block B instead of block A. Otherwise, I either get the *"Missing } inserted"* or the *"Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line X"* error. Obviously, I only want one of block A or B. So, what do I need to do in order to properly mask `&` (or `\\`, if that's the problem)?

Comment: the error isn't from the `\if` really, in the false case you are generating a row `{ a & b \\}` which would generate the error you show even without the conditional. What is the intention of adding the brace group?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, David. So, I'd like the code to work in both cases, with `\@testfalse` and without. It seemed to be the empty `{}`. If I remove all brace groups, it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: the empty `{}` wouldn't error it's just adding an empty brace group in the same cell as `a` (although the space after it would affect the spacing)

Comment: David: In fact, I abstracted the MWE from package code. I will replace the MWE by one that more closely matches the problem that remains after your recommendations.

Comment: ok but same answer you are adding brace groups (they are not delimiting arguments) and you can't have a brace group starting in one cell and finishing in another.

Comment: Alright, I understand that, but how to I get the code working with `\@testtrue` and `\@testfalse` without using brace groups mutually in the unused/unexpanded `if` branch?

Comment: I'm happy to move the discussion to the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129697/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-mario).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The error you show isn't from the conditional but from you starting a group with `{` in one row and trying to end it in the following row:

```
{ a & b \\}
```

Without the group you get the intended effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@test\@testtrue
% \@testfalse
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  % \if@test\else a & b \\ \fi
  \if@test\else a & b \\ \fi
  \if@test        c & d \\ \else\fi
\end{tabular}

\@testfalse

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  % \if@test\else a & b \\ \fi
  \if@test\else a & b \\ \fi
  \if@test        c & d \\ \else\fi
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

After the question was clarified I suspect you are looking for something like

with `\@testfalse`: [image]

without `\@testfalse`: [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@test\@testtrue
\newcommand{\thisline}[2]{\if@test\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{}{ \\ #1 & #2 }}
\newcommand{\thatline}[2]{\if@test\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{ \\ #1 & #2 }{}}
\@testfalse % <-- un-/comment

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\thisline{a}{b}
\thatline{c}{d}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works in this simple case but the interaction of `\if` conditionals and expansion of the `\halign` template inplementing the table is "interesting" and I'd avoid this design if possible. It is inherently fragile.